# Prove the convergence of this sequence

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

I have read the following problem. Let $(a_n)_n$ be a convergent sequence and let $b_n:=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(-1)^{i+1}a_i$ be the accompanying alternating partial sum that is multiplied by $\frac{1}{n}$. Show that the sequence $(b_n)_n$ converges to $0$.

I haven't done problems like these for quite some time, so I couldn't really come up with an answer. The sum to $n$ and $\frac{1}{n}$ made it seem that maybe I could work with some boundedness argument, so I tried something like the following. Since $(a_n)_n$ is convergent, it is bounded by some $c$. Thus we have that $$|b_n|\leq \sum_{i} \frac{1}{n} |a_i| \leq c$$ but this doesn't help me at all it seems, especially not for an epsilon argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix $\epsilon > 0$ and let $a$ and $n_0$ be such that $n\geq n_0$ implies $|a_n-a| < \epsilon$. Then
$$ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^{i+1} a_n = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n_0}(-1)^{i+1}a_i + \frac{1}{n}\sum_{n_0+1}^{n} (-1)^{i+1} a +  \frac{1}{n}\sum_{n_0+1}^{n} (-1)^{i+1} \epsilon_i, $$
where $\epsilon_i := a_n - a$.
The first sum converges to zero trivially. Now $\sum_{n_0+1}^n(-1)^{i+1}a $ is either $0$ or $\pm a$, so again $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{n_0+1}^n(-1)^{i+1} a$ converges to zero. Finally, $\sum_{n_0+1}^n\epsilon_i$ is at least $-n\epsilon$ and at most $n\epsilon$, so that $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{n_0+1}^{n}(-1)^{i+1} \epsilon_i $ is at least $-\epsilon$ and at most $\epsilon$.

Comment: Thanks, that makes perfect sense. The intuition behind it isnt as transparent to me right now, so it might be that I will ask more about that later, when I have more time, in case I can't get suitable intuition. Anyways, thanks a lot.

Comment: By the way, I think you mean $\epsilon_i$ in the two sequences at the end of your answer.

Comment: @user103178981 No problem, if you have some questions later on just post a comment. And you are right, those should be $\epsilon_i$. My intuition on this is "after some point $a_n$ is roughly a constant", so we should handle what happens before that point (the first sum), and then handle what the 'roughly' means, the last sum

Answer (score 2):

There is a general theorem that if $b_k\to b$ then $${1\over n}\sum_{k=1}^nb_k\to b$$ Let $$b_k=(-1)^{k+1}[a_k-a_{k-1}]=(-1)^{k+1}a_k+(-1)^ka_{k-1}$$ where $a_0=0.$ Then $b_k\to 0.$ Hence $${1\over n}\sum_{k=1}^nb_k={2\over n}\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k+1}a_k-{1\over n}(-1)^{n+1}a_n\to 0$$ The last term tends to $0.$ Therefore $${1\over n}\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k+1}a_k\to 0$$